# How to track or at least detect an invalid email address

Tags: java, php, ruby, django, email

I am using django. I just want to know is it possible to check if an email is a correct one, so that it will be definitely delivered (99.99%)? If the user entered an email like `klsdfksdajkfdn@skjdnf.com`, it is technically a valid email but does not exist really. Can I detect such emails?

Comment: I think, you can check only domain name.

Comment: There actually is a command for checking the existence of a username on a mail server, VRFY, but it's unreliably implemented because it can occasionally be useful to spammers.

Comment: Not possible really, well you can't be 100% on it. Most sites ask users to confirm their e-mail address by clicking a link after having one sent to them for this reason.

Comment: All you could do for email validation is check for the white list characters for user name and check domain name ,I mean the values which are valid for email address,If you want to do what you are saying then chances are you might miss some valid email address also , because only email server of that specific domain can validate that user name but this is valid quetion though :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way to achieve that is to provide a mechanism where the user to whom you send the e-mail receives a link asking for confirmation. Like you have in many subscriptions to websites. By this the user confirms that it is a valid e-mail that you can then 'trust'

Answer (score 2):

You cannot check email either before or after sending. 
But you can do *something* that will probably cover 80% of cases.

1. You can check domain. If for example the email given by user is `foo@gmail.com` first ping `gmail.com`. If it does not exist it probably the first red flag that email is wrong. But be careful: probably ICMP is blocked for this domain.
2. You can listen for auto-reply messages and try to distinguish those that tell you that email does not exist. This is to detect wrong user names while domain name is correct. But be careful: there can be both false negatives (if you recognize out-of-office reply as a email-does-not-exist) or false positives (if you just miss the auto reply because it does not contain expected words or is written in unexpected language)
3. If you cannot send email because `IOException` or stuff like this is thrown. But again, be careful: this can mean that the mail server from other side is temporary unavailable or that your computer has connectivity problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the email **non**-delivery report, or "bounce messages", tracking them isn't really in the purview of Django.  The messages themselves are emails, deposited in your mailbox by the mail daemon, and therefore you will need to properly configure your mail server and handle the mail that comes in via some system other than Django.

If you mean tracking actual delivery of an email, there are no good options.  "Read receipts" are only handled by some email clients, in incompatible ways, and all of those are probably email-based themselves and therefore not going to hit the webserver.  You could embed an image with a unique URL (a tracking image) and track who accesses it with Django, but because that's a bit of an invasion of privacy, some email clients like gmail will block the loading of those images (actually, all images) by default.

Checking if an email is correct is similarly complex.  You can easily find out if the domain part of the address is real, by attempting to query that domain's mail server directly, but only some mail servers will report whether a name is valid whereas some will not.

The best way by far is to simply *send a confirmation email* and require the user to respond to it by clicking a unique link, which leads to a Django page that marks that that email is definitely correct.  Indeed, most websites that use email communication do just this.  If you just want this functionality and no other email/account related functionality, maybe look at http://code.google.com/p/django-email-confirmation/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a reliable solution is possible using current generation email transmission protocols (i.e. SMTP).  Just about anything you could think of trying is beset with complexities and "failure" cases that will give you false positives or false negatives.

And even if you even (appear to) deliver an email to the destination mail server, you have no way of knowing if it will be delivered to anyone ... let alone the right person.  You can't even rely on the destination server telling you that it cannot deliver.

Realistically, you are probably best of doing a syntax check of the email address, and (maybe) looking to see if there is a DNS entry for the domain part of the email address.

---

Note that a lot of the obfuscation that happens in mail delivery is done in an attempt to discourage spammers.